# where is the default commit message for svn stored?

Tags: svn, commit, freebsd

I just upgraded subversion on FreeBSD 8.2 RELEASE. Now, when I commit using svn commit the svn-commit.tmp is already pre-filled with this:

```
PR:             
Submitted by:   
Reviewed by:    
Approved by:    
Obtained from:  
MFC after:      
Security:       
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--
> Description of fields to fill in above:                     76 columns --|
> PR:            If a GNATS PR is affected by the change.
> Submitted by:  If someone else sent in the change.
> Reviewed by:   If someone else reviewed your modification.
> Approved by:   If you needed approval for this commit.
> Obtained from: If the change is from a third party.
> MFC after:     N [day[s]|week[s]|month[s]].  Request a reminder email.
> Security:      Vulnerability reference (one per line) or description.
> Empty fields above will be automatically removed.
```

I've tried to Google where to turn this off, but no luck. I'd like the svn-commit.tmp pre-filled text to as it was before, simply:

```
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--
```

Does anyone know where the default commit text for an svn commit is stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FreeBSD version of SVN includes this text in the executable. The only way to remove these lines is to build the `devel/subversion` port yourself and turn off the `FREEBSD_TEMPLATE` option.

Comment: Arg! Thank you so much. It got rebuilt via portmaster as a dependency, so that option happened silently. Thanks!